# Alternative to blocking code

Tags: c, blocking, nonblocking, mbed

Attempting to use mbed OS scheduler for a small project.

As mbed os is Asynchronous I need to avoid blocking code.

However the library for my wireless receiver uses a blocking line of:

```
while (!(wireless.isRxData()));
```

Is there an alternative way to do this that won't block all the code until a message is received?

```
static void listen(void) {
    wireless.quickRxSetup(channel, addr1);
    sprintf(ackData,"Ack data \r\n");
    wireless.acknowledgeData(ackData, strlen(ackData), 1);
    while (!(wireless.isRxData()));
    len = wireless.getRxData(msg);  
}

static void motor(void) {
    pc.printf("Motor\n");
    m.speed(1);
    n.speed(1);
    led1 = 1;
    wait(0.5);
    m.speed(0);
    n.speed(0);
}

static void sendData() {
    wireless.quickTxSetup(channel, addr1);
    strcpy(accelData, "Robot");
    wireless.transmitData(accelData ,strlen(accelData));
}

void app_start(int, char**) { 
    minar::Scheduler::postCallback(listen).period(minar::milliseconds(500)).tolerance(minar::milliseconds(1000));   
    minar::Scheduler::postCallback(motor).period(minar::milliseconds(500));
    minar::Scheduler::postCallback(sendData).period(minar::milliseconds(500)).delay(minar::milliseconds(3000));
}
```

Comment: Threading and callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `while (!(wireless.isRxData()));` loop in your `listen` function. Replace it with:

```
if (wireless.isRxData()) {
    len = wireless.getRxData(msg);
    // Process data
}
```

Then, you can process your data in that if statement, or you can call `postCallback` on another function that will do your processing.

Comment: I am currently using that at the minute,unfortunately it means it doesn't pick up every message

Comment: In that case, I would try doing `while(wireless.isRxData())` instead of `if (wireless.isRxData())`. Also, you could try decreasing your period and tolerance when you post the `listen` callback.

Comment: Thanks, I am using that approach now just need to do some experimenting with the period and tolerance to get the responsiveness of the system right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping until data is available, you'll want to poll for data.  If RX data is not available, exit the function and set a timer to go off after a short interval.  When the timer goes off, check for data again.  Repeat until data is available.  I'm not familiar with your OS so I can't offer any specific code.  This may be as simple as adding a short "sleep" call inside the `while` loop, or may involve creating another callback from the scheduler.

Comment: Do you mean polling it with say an if statement instead of a while loop? so if data is available else sleep. Then have another callback?

Comment: @UniqueName- Keep the while loop, just add something inside of it that relinquishes control of the CPU for a short while.  On some OSes, you can do that with something like `while (!isRxData()) { usleep(10); }`.